# Does anyone know of a good OData explorer?

Tags: odata

Our software has an OData API and we would like to package it with a good OData explorer so that developers can easily discover the properties and methods.

We have found this one:

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/odataexplorer/

But it doesn't work in some cases and is pretty crappy.  We need something that is intuitive and polished.

Answer (score 11):

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) will let you connect to WCF Data Services, [including OData endpoints](https://web.archive.org/web/20110319235542/http://openlightgroup.net/Blog/tabid/58/EntryId/98/OData-Simplified.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to find an online tool that is used for OData only...

Answer (score 5):

The tool you are looking for is [Sesame Data Browser](http://metasapiens.com/sesame/data-browser/preview/).
It's a Silverlight application that works online.

Comment: Yes! ODataExplorer is a great ideal but would not work on 2K08R2. Sesame worked like a charm. Install on desktop to avoid cross-domain issues.

Comment: Sesame looks pretty cool, but doesn't seem to support JSON.

Comment: Time to delete this answer, Silverlight is dead.

Answer (score 2):

For out-of-box application, you can use Tableau or Excel (with PowerPivot) to explorer your service and data

For web based library, you can check about datajs project which have published one ODataQueryBUilder js library recently. Refer to this blog for more detail: http://www.odata.org/blog/odataquerybuilder-a-cross-browser-javascript-library-for-building-odata-queries-3/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried LinqPad recently but I found out that it's too strict on parsing OData XMLs, so making it work for some less-compliant OData services is very hard.

[OData Viewer Tool](http://dataservicestool.codeplex.com/) worked perfectly for me (and it has a source code, which is also nice)

Comment: Time to delete this answer, CodePlex is dead.